# VSCode: Autocompletion stops working from time to time

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code the autocompletion sometimes stops working after some time. When I restart the app it works again.
How can I fix this without always restarting the app?

System: macOS Catalina 10.15.2
VsCode Version: 1.41.1

Comment: try pressing `command + space`

Comment: This does not work then.

Comment: inside your settings.json paste this ` "editor.suggest.maxVisibleSuggestions": 5` also make sure and `Word Based Suggestions` must be checked in your settings. To Open the settings Press `Command or Ctrl + ,`.

Comment: Thanks, I will work for a few hours and then give an answer if this works!

Comment: The problem has resurfaced -.- Any idea?

Comment: Most likely, the specific extension in charge of providing the item list is crashing. As slightly less intrusive alternative to restarting the program, you can run the **Reload Window** command.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! But this whole thing is not at all satisfactory. I hope that Microsoft will send an update with a fix… Or am I the only one with this problem? 